# Nginx - How to block all IPs except one

Tags: nginx, configuration, server

I'm a total Nginx newbie and I need some help. =]

I have a list of IPs contained within "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for" which contains IPs separated by commas in this format:  "IP, Next IP".

I'd like to return a 403 error code if MY IP is not within this comma separated list.

I thought the easiest way to do it would be to do a simple if statement to say:  If $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for doesn't contain MY IP return 403.

Having tried this for ages I can't get anything to work, can anyone help me out?  It sounds like this should be really easy.

**Edit:**  Also I'm trying to set this up within the location block because there are other configurations using the Nginx and the IP restriction is only valid for this specific block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your IP address is `123.123.123.123`, then the following statement will return 403 if your IP address is **not** present:

```
if ($proxy_add_x_forwarded_for !~ \b123\.123\.123\.123\b) { return 403; }
```

It uses the `\b` metacharacter to enforce word boundaries (which includes digits) so that the complete IP address is tested.

You can place the expression within a location block if you need to reduce its scope.

The `if` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` directive. A useful resource for regular expressions is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).